Configuring sbatch to reserve resources required by dask_jobqueue.SLURMCluster
I am attempting to use a SLURMCluster to run a large project in parallel.  The cluster is set up in my script and then scaled with SLURMCluster.scale(N), to request N workers (where each is a node).
This works fine when there are N nodes available on the cluster when the batch job starts, but if there are not then the other jobs sit idle waiting for resources whilst dask runs on fewer cores.  I am trying to find a way to request N+1 nodes (number of workers + scheduler) in my sbatch script, so the job will only start when all of the resources are available.  (The cluster has a job time limit so I would like to maximize the running time will full resources, without them waiting.)
Requesting N+1 nodes in the SBATCH options runs the script N+1 times.  Requesting just 1 node will start the scheduler even if there are no nodes available for the workers.  I am looking for a way I can request the total resources expected by a job, or alternatively to reconfigure my workflow to ensure I can run my dask job with the full resources available.

I figured out a way of doing this by making a custom cluster in the sbatch script and then connecting the client to this instead of using SLURMCluster directly.

You can also use dask-mpi for this use case.
